# Iterate over a list plus one value using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In a checksum calculation algorithm I'm implementing, the input must be an even number of bytes -  if it isn't an extra zero byte must be packed at the end.

I do not want to modify the input data to my method by actually adding an element (and the input might be non-modifiable). Neither do I want to create a new data structure and copy the input.

I wondered if LINQ is a good option to create a lightweight `IEnumerable` something like:

```
void Calculate(IList<byte> input)
{
 IEnumerable<byte> items = (input.Count & 1 ==0) ? items : X(input,0x0);
 foreach(var i in items)
 {
   ...
 } 
}
```

i.e. what would `X(...)` look like?

Comment: Do you know the length of `input` in-advance? `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a `.Count` property. You must either enumerate over an `IEnumerable<T>` to get its length, or accept an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead (which is `IEnumerable<T> + `Int32 Count { get; }`).

Comment: Good catch... I'll amend my pseudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1) method for that

```cs
IEnumerable<byte> items = input.Count() % 2 == 0 ? input : input.Concat(new[] { (byte)0x0 });
```

I've also changed your code a little bit, there is no `Count` property for `IEnumerable<T>`, you should use `Count()` method.

Since `Concat()` accepts `IEnumerable<T>`, it requires to a `List<T>` ao array to it. You can make a simple extension method to wrap a single item as `IEnumerable<T>`

```cs
internal static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

and use it

```cs
IEnumerable<byte> items = input.Count() % 2 == 0 ? input : input.Concat(((byte)0x0).Yield());
```

However, according to comments, the better option here can be an [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
IEnumerable<byte> items = input.Count() % 2 == 0 ? input : input.Append((byte)0x0);
```

Comment: Using `.Count()` does mean iterating over `input` twice, however.

Comment: @Dai Isn't `Count` an O(1) operation?

Comment: If source collection implements `ICollection<T>` it'll take count from it, according to [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, but currently Linq only checks for `ICollection<T>`. It does not check for `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` - which is a problem because (until .NET 5 - I hope!) `ICollection<T>` does not extend `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, so `IList<T>` doesn't extend `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` either.

Comment: @Dai that's true, but is using `IEnumerable<T>`, and didn't mentioned anything about `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I meantioned `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` because it's the "next interface-up" (as far as specialization is concerned) because `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is identical to `IEnumerable<T>` except it adds `Count` (as a property-getter). Whereas `ICollection<T>` is a *mutable* interface and so many types cannot implement `ICollection<T>` at all.

Comment: FWIW I can probably widen my scope to `IList` or `ICollection` but as you point out, your solution works with either - or an explicit parameter could be passed in

Comment: Actually a better method would be [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netcore-3.1) so you don't have to create an array or write that `Yeild` method.

Comment: @juharr please provide an answer if you have a better solution?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I just spenda  confusing few minutes wondering why I couldn't find that method - turns out it was added to .net Framework in 4.7.1 onwards. It must be one of the last changes to that platform, so I think covering both in your answer is the best as you have

Comment: @Mr.Boy You are welcome. Yes, this method is exist for .NET FW 4.7.1 and later and .NET Core. Sorry, I didn't mentioned that:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this iterator (`yield return`) extension method to add extra items to the end of an `IEnumerable<T>` without needing to initially iterate over the elements (which you would need to do in-order to get a `.Count` value).

Note that you should check if `input` is an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or an `IList<T>` because that means you can use a more optimal code path when the `.Count` can be known in-advance.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnsureModuloItems<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 modulo, T defaultValue = default )
{
    if( source is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if( modulo < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( nameof(modulo), modulo, message: "Value must be 1 or greater." );

    //

    Int32 count = 0;
    foreach( T item in source )
    {
        yield return item;
        count++;
    }

    Int32 remainder = count % modulo;
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < remainder; i++ )
    {
        yield return defaultValue;
    }  
}
```

Used like so:

```
foreach( Byte b in input.EnsureModuloItems( modulo: 2, defaultValue: 0x00 ) )
{

}
```